# Extract agent from ray.tune

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I have been using azure machine learning to train a reinforcement learning agent using ray.tune.

My training function is as follows:

```
    tune.run(
        run_or_experiment="PPO",
        config={
            "env": "Battery",
            "num_gpus" : 1,
            "num_workers": 13,
            "num_cpus_per_worker": 1,
            "train_batch_size": 1024,
            "num_sgd_iter": 20,
            'explore': True,
            'exploration_config': {'type': 'StochasticSampling'},
        },
        stop={'episode_reward_mean': 0.15},
        checkpoint_freq = 200,
        local_dir = 'second_checkpoints'
        
    )
```

How can I extract the agent from a checkpoint so I can visualise the actions on my gym environment as follows:

```
while not done:
    action, state, logits = agent.compute_action(obs, state)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    episode_reward += reward
    print('action: ' + str(action) + 'reward: ' + str(reward))
```

I understand I can use something like this:

```
analysis = tune.run('PPO",config={"max_iter": 10}, restore=last_ckpt)
```

But I am unsure on how to pull the computing actions (and reward) from the agent that exists within tune.run.

Answer (score 1):

The tune run is used to train the model. After the training you should have some checkpoint files. These files can be loaded and then played in your env.

```
agent = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=env_name)
agent.restore(checkpoint_file)
obs = env.reset()
action = agent.compute_action(obs)
obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
```